# Regex not working properly in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this data:

```
{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}
```

And I want to use `preg_match_all` to filter out the words in between quotation like this:

```
$s = $data;

if (preg_match_all('/"([^:]*)"/', $s, $matches)) {
        echo join("\n", $matches[1]);
}
```

But this is outputting `names George","Eric","Alice` I tried many things but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: `json_decode()` to the rescue `print_r(json_decode('{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}', true));` !

Comment: Its JSON but Im using it as plain text in my project

Comment: @Youss It's very clear that this is just to show what the array will contain. You only have to call the elements of this array or just use `join()`.

Comment: @HamZa I tried all day what you are suggesting but I failed, that's why Im looking for a different approach to the problem, thanks anyway

Comment: @Youss What about `$arr = json_decode($input, true); $output = join('\n', $arr['names']);`. It's really this *simple*

Comment: Also if you tried *all day* like you suggested, I would say go refresh or learn PHP further. This is a trivial thing that I can't even call a "problem".

Comment: @HamZa You have the variable 'names' This is the problem, Im scraping the JSON and I dont know the variable upfront, the JSON is not mine and the data keeps changing

Comment: @Youss ok, you haven't mentioned that beforehand. But you could use a `foreach($arr, $key => $value){}` loop, it actually depends on how random your source is. Anyways, parsing JSON with regex isn't "recommended" it's still possible with regex though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` matches greedy (as much as possible). Use non-greey version: `*?`

```
if (preg_match_all('/"([^:]*?)"/', $s, $matches)) {
    echo join("\n", $matches[1]);
}
```

output:

```
names
George
Eric
Alice
```

**UPDATE**

`json_decode` is more appropriate for this kind of work. Try following:

```
foreach (json_decode($s, true) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "\n";
    echo join("\n", $value);
}
```

Comment: Don't treat json data like strings! Bad practice.

Comment: @Roebie, I updated the answer. I just wanted to tell the reason why OP get the result.

Comment: @falsetru: Sorry, our comments crossed.

Comment: You have the variable 'names' This is the problem, Im scraping the JSON and I dont know the variable upfront, the JSON is not mine and the data keeps changing

Comment: If the data keeps changing, a regex couldn't be trusted either. I've updated my answer too to skip the hard-coded names.

Comment: @falsetru Thank you very much, that last update makes more sense to me:)

Comment: Actually you need a [complexer regex](http://regex101.com/r/iD0hV8) to take into account escaped double quotes `(?<!\\)"((?:[^\\]|\\.)*?)"`

Answer (score 2):

This is actually JSON string use `json_decode` to parse it rather than using regex on this:

```
print_r(json_decode('{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}', true));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [names] => Array
        (
            [0] => George
            [1] => Eric
            [2] => Alice
        )

)
```

Comment: The thing is Im outputting this as plain text not as json. I really just need the words not the quotation, brackets and so on. (my project requires it to be plain text..)

Comment: Then `json_decode` can be used as: `print_r(json_decode($data, true));` where `$data` is your variable containing this plain text. That is much cleaner and safer than regex.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$strContent = '{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}';
$strRegex = '%\"(.+?)\"%s';
if (preg_match_all($strRegex, $strContent, $arrMatches))
{
    var_dump($arrMatches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is json formatted you should really treat is as json and not process it with regex which is to be used for strings. Try this:

```
$json = '{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data['names'] as $item) echo "$item\n";
```

Or without the hard coded "names":

```
$json = '{"names":["George","Eric","Alice"]}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $arr) foreach($arr as $item) echo "$item\n";
```